# Centos OpenJDK1.8 install OpenJFX

Tags: java, docker, openjfx

I have a docker image where the building process roughly looks like this:

```
FROM centos:latest
...
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
...
```

I highly depend on the specific java version, so changing that is not an option.

Right now I need to add openjfx to this and make it work, yet all the available documentation seems to be not working on my centos/openjdk combination.

[Downloading the zip file](http://gluonhq.com/download/javafx-11-0-2-sdk-linux/) and adding it to my container and running the following commands as described [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx):

```
RUN export PATH_TO_FX=/var/lib/javafx/lib \
    && javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX.java \
    && java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX
```

Failes, as:

> javac: invalid flag: --module-path

What would be the correct way to add it to this docker image?

Comment: "yet all the available documentation seems to be not working on my centos/openjdk combination" Please, describe what you've actually done, otherwise we may be ending just repeating what you already tried.

Comment: What does  `--module-path is not known in the container` mean? You mean if not use container, use this version's javac, it's ok but if use this version's java in container it throw error?

Comment: javac: invalid flag: --module-path

Comment: You may want to add a link to the documentation you have followed to help us better understand your issue. Also I think `--module-path` is a new addition of Java 9, part of the changes introduces with [Java modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), so it is normal that it does not work with Java 8.

Comment: My memory may be a bit confused, but isn't JavaFX already included in OpenJDK 8? You shouldn't need to add paths to the libraries etc...

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the error package javafx.util does not exist